# Слишком большие варианты в select

Tags: html, bootstrap

Слишком длинные варианты в селект, всё видно на скрине. Как это можно исправить? Вот код :

```
    <div class="form-group row ml-1">
       <label for="id1" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">orgId:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-5">
         <select class="form-control" id="id8">
    <option  disabled>Выберите тип участника</option>
    <option selected value="участник информационного обмена, 

    осуществляющий
    деятельность оператора по
    переводу денежных средств, –
    номер лицензии, выданной
    Банком России">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность оператора по
    переводу денежных средств, –
    номер лицензии, выданной
    Банком России</option>
        <option  value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность оператора услуг
    платежной инфраструктуры, –
    регистрационный номер
    оператора услуг платежной
    инфраструктуры">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность оператора услуг
    платежной инфраструктуры, –
    регистрационный номер
    оператора услуг платежной
    инфраструктуры</option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность оператора
    платежной системы, –
    регистрационный номер
    оператора платежной системы">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность оператора
    платежной системы, –
    регистрационный номер
    оператора платежной системы</option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность профессионального
    участника рынка ценных бумаг, –
    номер лицензии, выданной
    Банком России">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность профессионального
    участника рынка ценных бумаг, –
    номер лицензии, выданной
    Банком России</option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность управляющей
    компании инвестиционного
    фонда, паевого инвестиционного
    фонда и негосударственного
    пенсионного фонда, – номер
    лицензии, выданной Банком
    России">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность управляющей
    компании инвестиционного
    фонда, паевого инвестиционного
    фонда и негосударственного
    пенсионного фонда, – номер
    лицензии, выданной Банком
    России/option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность
    специализированного
    депозитария инвестиционного
    фонда, паевого инвестиционного
    фонда и негосударственного
    пенсионного фонда, – номер
    лицензии, выданной Банком
    России">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность
    специализированного
    депозитария инвестиционного
    фонда, паевого инвестиционного
    фонда и негосударственного
    пенсионного фонда, – номер
    лицензии, выданной Банком
    России</option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность акционерного
    инвестиционного фонда,
    – номер
    лицензии, выданной Банком
    России">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность акционерного
    инвестиционного фонда,
    – номер
    лицензии, выданной Банком
    России</option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    клиринговую деятельность
    ,–номер лицензии, выданной
    Банком России;">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    клиринговую деятельность
    ,–номер лицензии, выданной
    Банком России;</option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность по выполнению
    функций центрального
    контрагента
    ,
    – регистрационный
    номер из книги государственной
    регистрации кредитных
    организаций;">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность по выполнению
    функций центрального
    контрагента
    ,
    – регистрационный
    номер из книги государственной
    регистрации кредитных
    организаций;</option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность организатора
    торговли
    ,
    – номер лицензии,
    выданной Банком России (справочник участников
    финансового рынка
    )
    ">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность организатора
    торговли
    ,
    – номер лицензии,
    выданной Банком России (справочник участников
    финансового рынка
    )
    </option>
    <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность центрального
    депозитария,– ОГРН;">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность центрального
    депозитария
    ,
    – ОГРН
    ;</option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    репозитарную деятельность
    ,
    –
    номер лицензии, выданной
    Банком России">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    репозитарную деятельность
    ,
    –
    номер лицензии, выданной
    Банком России</option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность субъект
    а
    страхового дела

,
– номер
лицензии, выданной Банком
России;">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность субъект
а
страхового дела
,
– номер
лицензии, выданной Банком
России;</option>
    <option value="участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность негосударственного
пенсионного фонд
а
,
– номер
лицензии, выданной Банком
России
(справочник участников
финансового рынка
)
;">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность негосударственного
пенсионного фонд
а
,
– номер
лицензии, выданной Банком
России
(справочник участников
финансового рынка
)
;</option>
    <option value="участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность микрофинансовой
организации,
– регистрационный номер записи в государственном
реестре микрофинансовых
организаций">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность микрофинансовой
организации,
– регистрационный номер записи в государственном
реестре микрофинансовых
организаций</option>
<option value="участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность кредитного
потребительского кооператива, –
ОГРН">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность кредитного
потребительского кооператива, –
ОГРН</option>
<option value="участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность жилищного
накопительного кооператива, –
ОГРН">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность жилищного
накопительного кооператива, –
ОГРН</option>

    <option value="участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность бюро кредитных
историй, – номер в
государственном реестре бюро
кредитных историй">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность бюро кредитных
историй, – номер в
государственном реестре бюро
кредитных историй</option>
    <option value="участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
актуарную деятельность –
регистрационный номер записи о
внесении сведений в единый
реестр ответственных актуариев">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
актуарную деятельность –
регистрационный номер записи о
внесении сведений в единый
реестр ответственных актуариев</option>
    <option value="участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность кредитного
рейтингового агентства, – номер
выданного бланка свидетельства
о внесении сведений о
юридическом лице в реестр
кредитных рейтинговых
агентств">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность кредитного
рейтингового агентства, – номер
выданного бланка свидетельства
о внесении сведений о
юридическом лице в реестр
кредитных рейтинговых
агентств</option>

    <option value="участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность
сельскохозяйственного
кредитного потребительского
кооператива, – номер в
государственном реестре
сельскохозяйственных
кредитных потребительских
кооперативов">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность
сельскохозяйственного
кредитного потребительского
кооператива, – номер в
государственном реестре
сельскохозяйственных
кредитных потребительских
кооперативов</option>
    <option value="участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность ломбарда, – номер
в государственном реестре
ломбардов">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность ломбарда, – номер
в государственном реестре
ломбардов</option>
    <option value="участник информационного
обмена (государственные
органы, иностранные организации, провайдеры,
разработчики программного
обеспечения, центры
компетенции по
противодействию киберугрозам
)
– полное наименование
организации">участник информационного
обмена (государственные
органы, иностранные организации, провайдеры,
разработчики программного
обеспечения, центры
компетенции по
противодействию киберугрозам
)
– полное наименование
организации</option>
   </select>
</div>
    </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кроме, как использование кастомной реализации элемента select, вряд ли можно что-то придумать. Вот, например, вариант с использованием плагина [Select2](https://select2.org/)

```js
$(function(){
  $('#id8').select2();
});
```

```css
.select2-container {
  max-width: 80vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group row ml-1">
       <label for="id1" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">orgId:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-5">
         <select class="form-control" id="id8">
    <option  disabled>Выберите тип участника</option>
    <option selected value="участник информационного обмена, 

    осуществляющий
    деятельность оператора по
    переводу денежных средств, –
    номер лицензии, выданной
    Банком России">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность оператора по
    переводу денежных средств, –
    номер лицензии, выданной
    Банком России</option>
        <option  value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность оператора услуг
    платежной инфраструктуры, –
    регистрационный номер
    оператора услуг платежной
    инфраструктуры">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность оператора услуг
    платежной инфраструктуры, –
    регистрационный номер
    оператора услуг платежной
    инфраструктуры</option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность оператора
    платежной системы, –
    регистрационный номер
    оператора платежной системы">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность оператора
    платежной системы, –
    регистрационный номер
    оператора платежной системы</option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность профессионального
    участника рынка ценных бумаг, –
    номер лицензии, выданной
    Банком России">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность профессионального
    участника рынка ценных бумаг, –
    номер лицензии, выданной
    Банком России</option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность управляющей
    компании инвестиционного
    фонда, паевого инвестиционного
    фонда и негосударственного
    пенсионного фонда, – номер
    лицензии, выданной Банком
    России">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность управляющей
    компании инвестиционного
    фонда, паевого инвестиционного
    фонда и негосударственного
    пенсионного фонда, – номер
    лицензии, выданной Банком
    России</option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность
    специализированного
    депозитария инвестиционного
    фонда, паевого инвестиционного
    фонда и негосударственного
    пенсионного фонда, – номер
    лицензии, выданной Банком
    России">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность
    специализированного
    депозитария инвестиционного
    фонда, паевого инвестиционного
    фонда и негосударственного
    пенсионного фонда, – номер
    лицензии, выданной Банком
    России</option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность акционерного
    инвестиционного фонда,
    – номер
    лицензии, выданной Банком
    России">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность акционерного
    инвестиционного фонда,
    – номер
    лицензии, выданной Банком
    России</option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    клиринговую деятельность
    ,–номер лицензии, выданной
    Банком России;">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    клиринговую деятельность
    ,–номер лицензии, выданной
    Банком России;</option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность по выполнению
    функций центрального
    контрагента
    ,
    – регистрационный
    номер из книги государственной
    регистрации кредитных
    организаций;">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность по выполнению
    функций центрального
    контрагента
    ,
    – регистрационный
    номер из книги государственной
    регистрации кредитных
    организаций;</option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность организатора
    торговли
    ,
    – номер лицензии,
    выданной Банком России (справочник участников
    финансового рынка
    )
    ">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность организатора
    торговли
    ,
    – номер лицензии,
    выданной Банком России (справочник участников
    финансового рынка
    )
    </option>
    <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность центрального
    депозитария,– ОГРН;">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность центрального
    депозитария
    ,
    – ОГРН
    ;</option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    репозитарную деятельность
    ,
    –
    номер лицензии, выданной
    Банком России">участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    репозитарную деятельность
    ,
    –
    номер лицензии, выданной
    Банком России</option>
        <option value="участник информационного
    обмена, осуществляющий
    деятельность субъект
    а
    страхового дела

,
– номер
лицензии, выданной Банком
России;">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность субъект
а
страхового дела
,
– номер
лицензии, выданной Банком
России;</option>
    <option value="участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность негосударственного
пенсионного фонд
а
,
– номер
лицензии, выданной Банком
России
(справочник участников
финансового рынка
)
;">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность негосударственного
пенсионного фонд
а
,
– номер
лицензии, выданной Банком
России
(справочник участников
финансового рынка
)
;</option>
    <option value="участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность микрофинансовой
организации,
– регистрационный номер записи в государственном
реестре микрофинансовых
организаций">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность микрофинансовой
организации,
– регистрационный номер записи в государственном
реестре микрофинансовых
организаций</option>
<option value="участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность кредитного
потребительского кооператива, –
ОГРН">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность кредитного
потребительского кооператива, –
ОГРН</option>
<option value="участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность жилищного
накопительного кооператива, –
ОГРН">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность жилищного
накопительного кооператива, –
ОГРН</option>

    <option value="участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность бюро кредитных
историй, – номер в
государственном реестре бюро
кредитных историй">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность бюро кредитных
историй, – номер в
государственном реестре бюро
кредитных историй</option>
    <option value="участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
актуарную деятельность –
регистрационный номер записи о
внесении сведений в единый
реестр ответственных актуариев">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
актуарную деятельность –
регистрационный номер записи о
внесении сведений в единый
реестр ответственных актуариев</option>
    <option value="участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность кредитного
рейтингового агентства, – номер
выданного бланка свидетельства
о внесении сведений о
юридическом лице в реестр
кредитных рейтинговых
агентств">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность кредитного
рейтингового агентства, – номер
выданного бланка свидетельства
о внесении сведений о
юридическом лице в реестр
кредитных рейтинговых
агентств</option>

    <option value="участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность
сельскохозяйственного
кредитного потребительского
кооператива, – номер в
государственном реестре
сельскохозяйственных
кредитных потребительских
кооперативов">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность
сельскохозяйственного
кредитного потребительского
кооператива, – номер в
государственном реестре
сельскохозяйственных
кредитных потребительских
кооперативов</option>
    <option value="участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность ломбарда, – номер
в государственном реестре
ломбардов">участник информационного
обмена, осуществляющий
деятельность ломбарда, – номер
в государственном реестре
ломбардов</option>
    <option value="участник информационного
обмена (государственные
органы, иностранные организации, провайдеры,
разработчики программного
обеспечения, центры
компетенции по
противодействию киберугрозам
)
– полное наименование
организации">участник информационного
обмена (государственные
органы, иностранные организации, провайдеры,
разработчики программного
обеспечения, центры
компетенции по
противодействию киберугрозам
)
– полное наименование
организации</option>
   </select>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Тогда этот select очень сильно отличается от других ipnut'ов   https://prnt.sc/m8cu1i

Comment: @PavelKutsubin, этот select "собирается" из обычных элементов, таких как `div`, `span` и т.д. А это значит, что к ним можно применять любые стили и подогнать их под общий вид.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/m8dk67 мне ещё бы сделать адаптивной эту штуку, никогда этим не занимался и с 1-ой попытки вышло вот так... Можешь помочь и можно закрывать вопрос)@media (max-width: 768px) {что мне надо тут включить и что дописать в дефолтном select2.css чтобы работало...} Если можно, могу как-нибудь списаться/связаться. Дело довольно срочное хех

Comment: @PavelKutsubin, обратите внимание на мой пример. Для элемента с классом `.select2-container` задана максимальная ширина. Собственно, этим свойством и его значением можно манипулировать, как угодно. Вот, [пример в песочнице](https://jsfiddle.net/g0os3nhj/)

Comment: а как высоту редачить? просто height не хочет в container.

Comment: @PavelKutsubin, высоту чего? И вообще, проще всего смотреть нужные элементы в консоли, чтобы понять какие стили и на что влияют и там же изменять/добавлять/удалять определенные стили, чтобы сразу видеть результат. После того, как добились нужного результата, переписываете откорретированные стили уже в CSS-файлы

Comment: Высоту этой строчки,селекта  пока  на него не нажали

Comment: @PavelKutsubin, [смотрим](https://jsfiddle.net/ued6or0L/) Только значением `!important` не нужно сильно злоупотреблять. Лучше сдлеать так, чтобы ваши стили шли после родных стилей плагина, чтобы они перекрывали их, или же править прямо в CSS-файле плагина